# "pylint (import error)" while import a module in the same folder with VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import, pylint

I'm building my code in VSCode using python 3.7.3.

The folder structure:

```
project 
├── main.py
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── foo.py
    └── boo.py
```

In foo.py:

```
import boo
boo.printBoo()
```

When I run foo.py it works. I can get the result I expect.

`This is boo`

But VSCode pops out:

> Unable to import 'boo' pylint(import-error)

Though the code works, is there a way that I can get rid of `pylint(import-error)`?

---

I have tried to change the import statement to

```py
from ..modules import boo as Boo
```

> error: attempted relative import with no known parent package

and

```py
import modules.boo as Boo
```

> error: No module named 'modules'

What is the problem, is it pylint's problem or did I misuse the import?

Comment: So in this case I can't test my module(foo.py) individually in VSCode?
-m works in cmd

Comment: try to add empty \_\_init\_\_.py in the project root directory.

Comment: Related:  [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/674039)

Answer (score 19):

Had the exact same problem, with two files co-existing in the same subfolder, executing just fine, but getting a `pylint(import-error)` in VSCode.

The **solution** for me was adding the following text to `<projectroot>/.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--init-hook",
        "import sys; sys.path.insert(0, './modules')"
    ]
}
```

Which adds that relevant "modules" subfolder to the paths where **pylint** will look, besides the project root folder

Answer (score 3):

The only way for `import boo` to work from `foo` in Python 3 is if you are running `foo.py` directly. If that's the case then you need to have VS Code open your `modules` directory and not `project`.

If you want to open `project`, then change the import to `from . import boo` and then you can do `python3 -m modules.foo`.